# How to leave a Whatsapp group without informing the entire group?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Gradually we realize that some Whatsapp groups are useless because what could be an important post is lost between tons of offtopic silly videos and images.

Mute the group still shows new images about new conversations.

Leaving the group creates discomfort among the participants.

How to leave a WhatsApp group without the other participants knowing?

Or is there any way to hide the group from the conversation list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking has not been implemented yet.

> How to leave a WhatsApp group without the other participants knowing?

Sorry. They will know when you leave: "Rogério Dec has left the group" will be there for all to see and know.

> Or is there any way to hide the group from the conversation list?

Partially. If you archive the group, it will disappear (actually go to the bottom) from the conversation list. However, when someone in the group sends a message, it will be seen again. Archive it again.